# How can I place a market or limit spot order using pybit/bybit?

Tags: ccxt, bybit, pybit

Here is some code that is working. However I cant confirm that the stop loss and take profits are being placed. I can see my buy order on bybit through the trading view, but nothing to indicate there is a tp or sl.

Could someone please provide some working/proven code?

I know there are ways to place extra orders to simulate this but I would prefer to avoid extra complexity if possible.

```
def place_order(testmode,type, symbol, side, takeprofitprice, stoplossprice,  qty):


    # Get the market data
    market_data = get_market_ask_price(testmode, symbol="BTCUSDT")
    
    # Get the market price
    market_price = float(market_data)
    # Calculate the take profit and stop loss prices
    params = {
    'stopLossPrice': stoplossprice,
    'takeProfitPrice': stoplossprice,
}
    request = {  
        "category":"spot",
        "symbol":"BTCUSDT",
        "side":side,
        "orderType":"Limit",
        "qty":str(qty), #in btc 
        "price":str(market_price),
        "timeInForce":"GTC",
        "orderLinkId":"spot-test-postonly",
        "stopLoss":str(stoplossprice),
        "takeProfit":str(takeprofitprice)
        }
    market_order = exchange.privatePostV5OrderCreate(request)
    logger("market order",market_order)   

    symbol = 'BTC/USDT'
    open_orders = exchange.fetch_open_orders(symbol=symbol)
    logger("open orders",pd.df(open_orders))
    
    return market_order
```